# Missing functionalities from CookComputing.XmlRpc and duplicated definitions

Tags: c#, python, .net, client, xml-rpc

I working on a distributed application on which my server is written with python programming language and the client is written with C#. To communicate both client and server, I have chosen to use xml-rpc. I have written my server on python and it works but when I started to use CookComputing.XmlRpc (I added references) library to write my C# client, many functionalities provided in the example provided in the official documentation are not existent and some others are duplicated which confused the compiler.
Here is the code:

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;

public struct SumAndDiffValue 
{
   public int sum; 
   public int difference; 
}

[XmlRpcUrl("http://www.cookcomputing.com/sumAndDiff.rem")] 
public interface ISumAndDiff : IXmlRpcProxy
{ 
   [XmlRpcMethod] 
   SumAndDiffValue SumAndDifference(int x, int y);
}
```

I get this errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'XmlRpcUrl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcUrlAttribute' exists in both 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcSilverlight.dll'    

The type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.IXmlRpcProxy' exists in both 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcSilverlight.dll'

The type or namespace name 'XmlRpcMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  

The type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcMethodAttribute' exists in both 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\CookComputing.XmlRpcSilverlight.dll'
```

what's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem that I have made a mistake while installing the new dll from xml-rpc.net, to avoid this problem it will be better to install it through nuget using this command:

```
Install-Package xmlrpcnet -Version 2.5.0
```